# TCP/IP Forwarding in Windows Vista and Above

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, networking, tcpip

[This is the way to do it on XP](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=315236), but is it possible on Windows Vista and Above?

If so how do you detect it? Is there a registry setting for it, or is there com dll or api for it?

Comment: take a look at here (http://www.chicagotech.net/netforums/viewtopic.php?t=1507)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same registry key should work on both Windows XP as well as Windows Vista/7.  [This document](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PdSwvkldcykJ:download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26893a6-46c7-4b5c-b287-830216597340/tcpip_reg.doc+http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26893a6-46c7-4b5c-b287-830216597340/TCPIP_Reg.doc&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) lists it as a valid key.  You may need to create it in order to use it.

You should be able to verify its state using the `ipconfig` command:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Look for the *IP Routing Enabled* under *Windows IP Configuration*

Comment: ipconfig does display whether IP routing is enabled or not. Thanks. You wouldnt happen to know if there is a com wmi or other api for this?

Comment: There is always the Windows Registry API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724871%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  Also, take a look at this reference http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692585.aspx